# What happens when an interface is Autowired vs the implementation

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am working on a spring project that has the Service layer divided in two packages:

- Interfaces
- Implementation

While calling methods declared in the interface and defined in the implementation, which of the two should be `@Autowired` for which purpose?

What is the difference in autowiring the interface and the implementation?

I ask these keeping in mind that the point of this abstraction is usually to hide the declaration from the implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there is only a single implementation of the interface and that implementation is annotated with `@Component` with Spring's component scan enabled, Spring framework can find out the (interface, implementation) pair.

Once you have more than one implementation, then you need to qualify each of them and during auto-wiring, you would need to use the `@Qualifier` annotation to inject the right implementation, along with `@Autowired` annotation. If you are using `@Resource` (J2EE), then you should specify the bean name using the name attribute of this annotation.

Normally, both will work, you can autowire interfaces or classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can always autowire interfaces, but if you are having multiple implementations of your interface then you will need to tell spring which implementation to consider, and there are multiple ways to do so.

1. either mark one of them as @Primary
2. define name of bean on implementation and use @Qualifier annotation while autowiring it

Comment: thanks for your response, but i am more trying to understand what is the difference in autowiring an interface and the implementaion. Even if there is a single implementation

Comment: so there is no difference technically, but it is a matter of best practices to leverage the abstraction part of OOP concepts